# Clone input on element click

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I have an image upload preview. And, when user click in `.thumb`, I want to clone the input text name and show this. But `clone()`isn't working.

thanks

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/emTAX/11/)**

HTML

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple /><br />
<output id="list"></output><br />
<p>Name:<input type="text" class="name"/><p>
<br />
```

JS

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

// Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
  // Only process image files.
  if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
    continue;

  }

  var reader = new FileReader();

  // Closure to capture the file information.
  reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
    return function(e) {
      // Render thumbnail.
      var span = document.createElement('span');
      span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                        '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
      document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
    };
  })(f);

  // Read in the image file as a data URL.
  reader.readAsDataURL(f);
}
}

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);

$('.thumb').click(function() {
$('p').clone();
});
```

Comment: your ('p').clone(); is missing the factory symbol $  .. $('p').clone();

Comment: Thanks...Edited!!! But, this is not the problem. =(

Comment: You're cloning, but then you aren't appending it to anything. Where do you want it to go?

Comment: also when you try to clone .name and appendTo .name .. you are making the .name clone a child of the first .name.. and input tags dont have child nodes .. you might want to not use appendTo or try to appendTo .name's parent so its clone can become its sibling .. http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/

Comment: Hi!! I've edited the fiddle and code with the appendTo. But doestwork yet. Thanks

Comment: posted my answer below .. the click event was not binding

Answer (score 0):

what about this..

im still confused about what you want to do.. but the click event wasnt working due to the image not being  there when the dom was ready, after the fact

http://jsfiddle.net/emTAX/25/

```
$('body').on("click",".thumb",function() {
     var myclone = $("p input").clone();
    $('p:first').append(myclone);
});
```

append() is faster than appendTo()

basically using on() will keep the event listening for the .thumb and then attach the event on it

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: do you just want to clone the input field or the p tag?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want to do. I don't know what you were doing with the .click, but I moved the HTML to your loop that generates the thumbs.

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/emTAX/17/

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        $('.name').clone().appendTo(".name");
        // Only process image files.
        if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
            continue;

        }

        var reader = new FileReader();

        // Closure to capture the file information.
        reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
            return function (e) {
                // Render thumbnail.
                var span = document.createElement('span');
                span.innerHTML = ('<img class="thumb" src="' + e.target.result + '" title="' + escape(theFile.name) + '"/><p>Name:<input type="text" class="name" /></p>');
                document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
            };
        })(f);

        // Read in the image file as a data URL.
        reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
}

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

Comment: What does it need to do differently?

Comment: Thanks!! You'r so close. I want that thumb appears, and when i click in it, this clone the p and show this.

Comment: So, you want the inputs to appear once you click on a picture?

Comment: Sorry, I was working on it, but I have to go. My advice is to have dynamic IDs and haev a function to show and hide them.

Comment: Ok. I will try. I think I will need your help. thanks